# Not able to delete multiple items from blocks using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an issues with deleting multiple blocks using following html.I am able to delete single block by using the below jquery.But I ham not getting an idea how to delete multiple blocks.To delete Multiple blocks I have check box,But its not working.I am pasting single delete jquery code below.Can anyone help me ,how to delete multiple blocks.I have pasted following html below

When I click on delete,A single block is deleted.That code I have pasted below.

```
$("#addSentiment").on("click", ".dialogs .itemdiv .tools span", function(e){
    $(this).closest('.dialogs .itemdiv').remove();
});
```

For deleting multiple blocks I have a check box outside  like this.I am using following Jquery code to checkall checkboxes when I click on the outer checkbox.**Basically Not able to delete multiple item by using jquery**

Code for select multiple blocks using checkbox (jquery)

```
$('#selecctall').click(function(event) {  //on click
    if(this.checked) { // check select status
        $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"              
        });
    }else{
        $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                      
        });        
    }
});

<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">

<input type="checkbox" id="selecctall">Multiple List 
<span class="delrt"><a id="del">Delete</a></span>

</h3>
</div>


<div id="addSentiment" class="dialogs"><div id="1" class="dialogs">
            <div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">


            <div class="body">


            <div class="name">
            <input type="checkbox" value="4502216" name="check[]" class="checkbox1">&nbsp;<a href="#">qwe@xxxx.com</a>
            </div>
            <div id="cat_1" class="text"><b>Category</b> : as<br></div>
            <div id="op_1" class="text"><b>Opissnion worssd/phrase</b> : One<br></div>
            <div id="feature_1" class="text"><b>Feassture wossrd/psshrase</b> : formal<br></div>
            <div id="score_1" class="text"><b>Score</b> : Positive<br></div>
            <div class="text"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="hd"></div>
            <div class="docidhd"><input type="hidden" value="4502216" name="hddocid" id="hddocid_1"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="cntupdt" id="cntupdt"></div>
            <div class="tools">
            <a id="edit_1" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info" href="#">
            <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>

            </a>
            <span class="dlt">
            <a id="delete_1" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info dlt" href="#">
            <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>
            delete
            </a>
            </span>
            </div>


            </div>
            </div></div><div id="2" class="dialogs">
        <div class="itemdiv dialogdiv">
<div class="body">

<div class="name">
<input type="checkbox" value="4502217" name="check[]" class="checkbox1">&nbsp;<a href="#">email@email.com</a>
</div>
<div id="cat_2" class="text"><b>Category</b> : Acsssaascess<br></div>
<div id="op_2" class="text"><b>Opinssion word/phrase</b> : testing opinssion<br></div>
<div id="feature_2" class="text"><b>Feassture word/phrase</b> : Thumsssbs up<br></div>
<div id="score_2" class="text"><b>Scssore</b> : possstive<br></div>
<div class="text"><input type="hidden" value="2" name="hd"></div>
<div class="docidhd"><input type="hidden" value="4502217" name="hddocid" id="hddocid_2"></div>
    <div class="tools">
            <a id="edit_2" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info" href="#">
<i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>                                                      
                </a>
<span class="dlt">
<a id="delete_2" class="btn acebtn btn-minier btn-info dlt" href="#">
                                                                        <i class="icon-only ace-icon fa fa-share"></i>                                                                  delete</a>
</span>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have pasted only 2 blocks.I may get unlimited blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".panel-heading").on("click", "#del", function(e) {
    $('.dialogs').find("input[name='check[]']:checked").closest('.dialogs').remove();
});
```

[http://jsbin.com/vexeto/1/](http://jsbin.com/vexeto/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

to get multiple items in your jquery selector string, use a comma `,`:

```
$(this).closest('.dialogs, .itemdiv').remove();
```